# Some Clarifications on Stack Exchange Post

Tags: support, specific-question, off-topic

See this [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698230/implementing-chat-api-widgets-in-web-app#comment18889870_13698230). This post was down voted and closed by some users. While I asked about that there, they redirected here.

What is wrong with my that post?

Answer (score 6):

As Will has already said in his comment, you're asking for software recommendations. That isn't within the scope of our site as it's essentially a polling/shopping question.

Asking for free API recommendations falls under the same category.